# How do I scrape data from a website using Java (Android)?

Tags: java, android, web-scraping, jsoup

My Android app will obtain carrier info from a phone number.  I intend to use Jsoup (or another Java HTML parser) to scrape carrier info displayed in a  table.

I am attempting to scrape from [fonefinder.net](http://fonefinder.net)

The query URL format is :

```
http://www.fonefinder.net/findome.php?npa=**first 3 digits**&nxx=**next 3 digits**&thoublock=**final 4 digits**
```

The HTML of the page is a simple table (see below).  I am trying to extract data from the 2nd row, 5th column, where a link appears in the format

```
http://fonefinder.net/(CARRIER_NAME).php
```

where CARRIER_NAME is a value like "verizon".  I need help figuring out how to extract this data.

```
<table border="3" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" bgcolor="#FFFFCC">
  <tbody>
    <tr bgcolor="#7093DB" align="CENTER">
      <th>
        Area Code
      </th>
      <th>Prefix</th>
      <th>
        City/Switch Name
        <br>
        (Click for city search)
      </th>
      <th>
        State/Prov.
        <br>
        Area Map
      </th>
      <th>
        Telephone Company
        <br/>
        Web link
      </th>
      <th>
        Telco
        <br/>
        Type
      </th>
      <th>
        Map/Zip
        <br/>
        Detail
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        **first 3 digits**
      </td>
      <td>
        **next 3 digits**
      </td>
      <td>
        City Name
      </td>
      <td>
        State Name
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="http://fonefinder.net/CARRIER_NAME.PHP">carrier name</a>
      </td>
      <td>WIRELESS PROV</td>
      <td>
        map
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Haven't you posted the very same question some hours ago?!?

Comment: will it be ok if I write a 2 line java code which gets you this information instead of using any third party parsers ?

Answer (score 0):

The code I wrote makes heavy use of Jsoup's selector syntax to parse tags by name, but you can also parse by CSS class, id, attribute and more.  The [Jsoup selector syntax documentation](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) has the full list of selectors that you can use.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class StackOverflowQuestion {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            // get the tables on this page, note I masked the phone number
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.fonefinder.net/findome.php?npa=###&nxx=###&thoublock=####").get();
            Elements tables = doc.select("table");

            // get the second table, 0 indexed
            Element secondTable = tables.get(1);

            // get the columns
            Elements tds = secondTable.select("td");

            //get the 5th column, 0 indexed
            Element fifthTd = tds.get(4);

            //get the link in this column
            Element link = fifthTd.select("a").first();

            //print out the URL
            System.out.println(link.attr("href"));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```